# Error in using the BSTR data type

Tags: c++, bstr, firebreath, type-conversion

My firebreath plugin project has a wrapper class of an active X control.

One of the method takes a BSTR data type variable as input, but when I try to call the method and pass a BSTR, i get an error.

I have even included the "WTypes.h" header file. But that doesnot seem to fix the problem.

So someone suggest an alternative.

```
short MakeCall (BSTR sNumber,short * nConnectionId );
```

The Makecall function  calls the Makecall function implemented by the active x control by using these paramters

The error

```
Error   1   error C2665: 'FB::variant_detail::conversion::convert_variant' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types   c:\users\research\downloads\firebreath-firebreath-firebreath-1.6.0rc1-15-g411c7fe\firebreath-firebreath-411c7fe\src\scriptingcore\variant.h 842 1   axWrapper
```

PS: After i searched about the error i find that fire breath doesnot support wide characters i.e uni code. So is there a way to use the unicode data type in firebreath.

Comment: @Taxilian I guess you could help

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore  I added the declaration of the function which uses the BSTR data type

Comment: You also need need to post the error that you are getting

Comment: "When I try to declare a variable as BSTR in my class I get an error." Please include the failed attempt to declare a BSTR. Also, generate (but do not post) the preprocessor output and verify that the definition of BSTR is included at the global namespace.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I added the error. I though the error was firebreath specific.So didnot include it previously

Comment: That does not look like the type of error associated with a member variable declaration. Please post your attempt to declare a BSTR member variable. (From reading between the lines, I think the error is your attempt to *use* a BSTR variable, not declare it. Specifically, you're trying to pass a BSTR variable to a function that does not accept BSTRs.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen That was what i intended. Am not able to use the BSTR variable in firebreath framework.

Comment: I'm still confused. You say that one of the methods takes a BSTR data type variable as input, yet when you pass a BSTR you get an error. Show us the method you are trying to call, and the code that tries to call it. (You also didn't say whether the method in question is a firebreath method or a method you wrote yourself) I'll try to edit your question to remove the misleading bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that you are trying to convert a FB::variant into a BSTR, which is not something that FB::variant knows how to do. Most likely that means that you're trying to use a BSTR as a type in a method you registered on a JSAPIAuto object. JSAPIAuto will automatically convert types, but you have to use types that it understands, and BSTR is not one of them.

Instead, find whatever method is registered as a JSAPI method and change the BSTR to a std::wstring; then convert the wstring into a BSTR. This should work fine.

FireBreath does support unicode; you can use std::wstring for wide characters and std::string types coming from the browser will be UTF8. You can #include "utf8_tools.h" and use FB::utf8_to_wstring and FB::wstring_to_utf8 to convert between them.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <atlbase.h>
```

should do the trick